# How to get mouse position in pdf?

Tags: c#, pdf, mouse-position, axacropdf

Is it possible to get mouse position or coordinates when I click anywhere in PDF (axAcroPdflib), because I want highlight area horizontally once I get coordinates using C#.

Comment: I guess it should be possible to determine if you have your mouse over the window and if the window is active, and then monitor mouse clicks... Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position`? It should be returning a point in X/Y coordinates.